# How can I fix my code to hide the div function on the second click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please see my code. I am just starting out and learning on the go.

It will show the function on click, but I would like it to hide on the second click. Also, once a button has been visited, it stays the "active" colour instead of reverting back to the default colour. I've got the "visited" colour to state the background default colour but this hasn't done the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#CalendarButton").click(function(){
    $("#Calendar").load("{OrgUnitPath}Calendar.html", function(){
      if(statusTxt == "success")
        alert();
      if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("EventsButton").click(function(){
    $("#Events").load("{OrgUnitPath}EVENTS.html", function(){
      if(statusTxt == "success")
        alert();
      if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#OHSButton").click(function(){
    $("#OHS").load("{OrgUnitPath}OHS.html", function(){
      if(statusTxt == "success")
        alert();
      if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#SystemsButton").click(function(){
    $("#Systems").load("{OrgUnitPath}SYSTEMS.html", function(){
      if(statusTxt == "success")
        alert();
      if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#TrainingButton").click(function(){
    $("#Training").load("{OrgUnitPath}TRAINING.html", function(){
      if(statusTxt == "success")
        alert();
      if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#QualityButton").click(function(){
    $("#Quality").load("{OrgUnitPath}QUALITY.html", function(){
      if(statusTxt == "success")
        alert();
      if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#OtherButton").click(function(){
    $("#Other").load("{OrgUnitPath}OTHER.html", function(){
      if(statusTxt == "success")
        alert();
      if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#CalendarButton").click(function(){
    $("#Events, #OHS, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other").hide();
    $("#Calendar").show();
    $("#CalendarButton").addClass("active");
    $("#Events, #OHS, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other").removeClass("active");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#EventsButton").click(function(){
    $("#Calendar, #OHS, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other").hide();
    $("#Events").show();
    $("#EventsButton").addClass("active");
    $("#Calendar, #OHS, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other").removeClass("active");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#OHSButton").click(function(){
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other").hide();
    $("#OHS").show();
    $("#OHSButton").addClass("active");
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other").removeClass("active");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#SystemsButton").click(function(){
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #OHS, #Training, #Quality, #Other").hide();
    $("#Systems").show();
    $("#SystemsButton").addClass("active");
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #OHS, #Training, #Quality, #Other").removeClass("active");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#TrainingButton").click(function(){
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #OHS, #Systems, #Quality, #Other").hide();
    $("#Training").show();
    $("#TrainingButton").addClass("active");
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other").removeClass("active");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#QualityButton").click(function(){
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #OHS, #Systems, #Training, #Other").hide();
    $("#Quality").show();
    $("#QualityButton").addClass("active");
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #Systems, #Training, #OHS, #Other").removeClass("active");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#OtherButton").click(function(){
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #OHS, #Systems, #Training, #Quality").hide();
    $("#Other").show();
    $("#OtherButton").addClass("active");
    $("#Calendar, #Events, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #OHS").removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#Calendar{
margin: 18.72px 0px 0px  0px}

#Calendar, #Events, #OHS, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other {
font-size: 90%!important;
}

.lg-row {
display:flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
}
/* Button overrides */
.lg-btn {
    float: left;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background:#008c7f;
}
.lg-btn span {
    flex-grow: 3;
    flex-shrink: 3;
    text-align: left;
}
a.lg-btn, a.lg-btn:hover {
    color: #fff!important;
}
a.lg-btn:hover {
    background-color: #01b6ad;
}
a.lg-btn:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.lg-btn:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-colour: #008c7f;

}
a.lg-btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.lg-btn:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.lg-btn-nav {
    width: 32.5%;
    height: 64px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 10px;
}
.active {background-color:#01b6ad;}

}
.visited {background-color:#008c7f;}

}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="lg-row">
<a class="lg-btn lg-btn-nav" id="CalendarButton"><em class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-2x pull-left"></em><span>Training Calendar</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg pull right"></i></a>
<a class="lg-btn lg-btn-nav" id="EventsButton"><em class="fa fa-ticket fa-2x pull-left"></em><span>Events</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg pull right"></i></a> </div>
<div class="lg-row">
<a class="lg-btn lg-btn-nav" id="OHSButton"><em class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x pull-left"></em><span>OHS</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg pull right"></i></a>
<a class="lg-btn lg-btn-nav" id="SystemsButton"><em class="fa fa-cogs fa-2x pull-left"></em><span>Systems</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg pull right"></i></a>
<a class="lg-btn lg-btn-nav" id="TrainingButton"><em class="fa fa-group fa-2x pull-left"></em><span>Training</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg pull right"></i></a>
<a class="lg-btn lg-btn-nav" id="QualityButton"><em class="fa fa-line-chart fa-2x pull-left"></em><span>Quality</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg pull right"></i></a>
<a class="lg-btn lg-btn-nav" id="OtherButton"><em class="fa fa-edit fa-2x pull-left"></em><span>Other</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg pull right"></i></a></p>
</div>

<div id="Calendar"></div>
<div id="Events"></div>
<div id="OHS"></div>
<div id="Systems"></div>
<div id="Training"></div>
<div id="Quality"></div>
<div id="Other"></div>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant to be utilized to clean up your code.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way, I was after help with the visited colour reverting to default and hiding the function more than a code clean. But I do know I'm only starting out and copying what I can from blog posts/ schools. Thank you for your help though - I really do appreciate your time.

Comment: If I run your code _in situ_ and then click on an icon (e.g. Training) then I get "ReferenceError: statusTxt is not defined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using .toggle() instead of .show() and .toggleClass() instead of .addClass() if you want the second click to undo your styles.

Also, when you remove the "active" class you'll want to simultaneously add the "visited" class. So, for example:

`$("#Calendar, #OHS, #Systems, #Training, #Quality, #Other").removeClass("active").addClass("visited");`

See the `.addClass("visited")` on the end.

Comment: Thanks you so much. And thank you for being specific in the codes placement. This did work, mostly! Except for the first time I click on any of the buttons nothing happens, then I click it again and the div will show but the button colour will be the default colour and if I click it a third time the div will hide but the colour will stay as the "active" colour. If I then click any other buttons they work perfectly (show/hide as well as the right colours when active/not active). Do you have any suggestions? This is still much better than what it was so thank you!

Comment: I mainly followed your lead and looked for quick fixes to make this work. I could continue down that line, but I think I should tell you that the main issue is that you've coded each button individually and created duplicative code. 

On reflection I'd like to recommend a different approach: add a class to all of the button divs and then create code that will work for any of them.

One way to do this might be to set every class member to it's inactive state and then set the individual button to the active state. I recommend reading the API documentation at jquery.com to help you with this.

Comment: Anyway, a quicker answer would be that you should set initial states for all the divs. Set them all to default to start with and you should get what you want. But, still, I think you might want to refactor this. Also, please upvote and mark accepted, if this is good. THANKS!